# Android returns an error when parsing JSON

Tags: android, json

I got an error in parsing JSON on Android. This is my JSON method:

```
void examineJSONFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //String x = "";
            String y = "";
            InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.utf);
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];

            try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")
              );
              int n;
              while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
              }
            } finally {
              is.close();
            }

            String jsontext = writer.toString();
            JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);


            int j;
            for (j=0;j<entries.length();j++)
            {
                JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(j);
                y += post.getString("description") + "\n";
            }
            txt_beschreibung.setText(y);
        }
        catch (Exception je)
        {
            txt_beschreibung.setText("Error w/file: " + je.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

This is the sample of my JSON file:

```
[{
  "title": "CARE Deutschland-Luxemburg e.V.",
  "keyword": "CARE",
  "description": "<p><b>Das CARE-Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not</b></p><p>Schnell, nachhaltig und durchdacht, das ist das moderne CARE-Paket. CARE ist überzeugt, dass umfassende Hilfe von drei Seiten notwendig ist, um die weltweite Armut Schritt für Schritt zu verringern. Deswegen hat CARE sich seit seiner Gründung 1945 und dem Abwurf der ersten CARE-Pakete über Berlin weiter entwickelt. Heute steckt im CARE-Paket weit mehr als Zucker und Mehl. Heute bietet die Organisation in 70 der ärmsten Länder der Welt ein Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not.</p><p><b>Das Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not enthält:</b></p>*sofortige Nothilfe nach Katastrophen<br><br>*langfristige Entwicklungszusammenarbeit<br><br>*Schutz der Menschenrechte<br><br>",
  "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1284113658.jpg",
  "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1284113658.jpg",
  "cost": "5"
  },
  {
  "title": "Brot für die Welt",
  "keyword": "BROT",
  "description": "<p>„Brot für die Welt“ unterstützt unter der Maßgabe 'Helfen, wo die Not am größten ist' ausgewählte Projekte weltweit.</p><p>Von Angola bis Tansania, von der Förderung von Mahlzeiten bis zur gesundheitlichen Grundversorgung und Katastrophenhilfe.</p><p>Bei ihrem täglichen Kampf gegen Krankheiten, Hunger, Ungerechtigkeiten und Armut wird die Aktion „Brot für die Welt“ von der evangelischen Kirche unterstützt.</p><p>Die Aktion hat es sich zum Ziel gesetzt, die Entwicklungszusammenarbeit auf der ganzen Welt zu fördern und Hilfe zur Selbsthilfe zu leisten.</p>",
  "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1267454286.jpg",
  "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1267454286.jpg",
  "cost": "5"
  }]
```

Comment: Can you post here your `jsontext` String (wich you obtain before `JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);`)

Comment: I don't have any, I only have this InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.utf);
so it will read the data from the JSON file (raw)

Comment: Log the jsontext var before constructing the jsonObject this will help you to track down the problem.

Comment: Try validating your whole string here: http://www.jsonlint.com/  The problem may not be in the example you've posted above.

Comment: I have removed an image from this post that was redirecting to the image host's homepage. I suspect they deleted it. As a result of this removal, there is no record in this post of the error condition encountered, so it should be put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [simple code from JavaCodeGeeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) will parse a JSON beautifully (see below).  As for specifically why your code is not working I do not know.

```
public class JsonParsingActivity extends Activity {

    String url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=javacodegeeks";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);

        SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);

        Toast.makeText(this, response.query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        List<Result> results = response.results;

        for (Result result : results) {
            Toast.makeText(this, result.fromUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {

           HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
           final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
              Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                  "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
              return null;
           }

           HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
           return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
           getRequest.abort();
           Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }

        return null;

     }

}
```